# The Doi-Naganuma Lift

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $F$=$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ be a real quadratic field
and $\mathcal{O}_F$ be the ring of integers of $F$.
The generating series $$\Omega^{(k)}(z_1, z_2, \tau ) := \sum^{\infty}_{m=1} m^{k-1} \omega^{(k)}_m(z_1, z_2) e^{2\pi i m \tau}$$ ($z_1$, $z_2$, $\tau$ $\in$ $\mathbb{H}$, the upper half plane) is both a Hilbert modular form (with respect to $z_1$ and $z_2$) and a classical modular form (with respect to $\tau$).
Here $$\omega^{(k)}_m(z_1, z_2) := \sum_{\scriptstyle{a,b\in \mathbb{Z},\ \ \lambda \in \delta^{-1},}\atop\scriptstyle{N(\lambda)-ab = \frac{m}{D}} }    \frac{1}{(a z_1 z_2 + \lambda z_1 + \lambda^{\prime} z_2 + b)^k},$$
where $\delta$ is the principal ideal $(\sqrt{D})$ and $\lambda^{\prime}$ denotes the conjugate of $\lambda$.

$\Omega^{(k)}(z_1, z_2, \tau )$ has been constructed by Zagier (reference: ["Modular forms associated to real quadratic fields"](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BF01389846/ModFormsRQF.pdf)). The [Petersson inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersson_inner_product) $\langle \cdot  , \Omega^{(k)} \rangle$ defines a linear map from classical cusp forms to Hilbert cusp forms, $S_k(\Gamma_0(D), \chi_D) \to S_{(k,k)}(SL_2(\mathcal{O}_F))$.

I'd like to know the history behind that. My question is :

> What was the motivation for the construction of $\Omega^{(k)}(z_1, z_2, \tau )$?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a nice question, IMHO, but it has nothing to do with arithmetic geometry as far as I can see. (I removed the tag and you seem to have added it back.)

Comment: Thanks for removing the tag. There is a geometric interpretation of the Doi-Naganuma lifting and it's adjoint. I amn't sure arithmetic-geometry tag would be suitable (Probably you can retag).